# create a folder in a specific path using Blender python

Tags: python, scripting, mesh

I'm trying to create a folder using python in blender and run in in blender text editor. I don't know how I can do this.

I want to export the vertices of a mesh in this specific created folder. Currently I'm doing this which create the file in the blender folder.

`fout = open("mesh.verts", "w")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out using:

```
os.mkdir('')
```

Comment: Blender includes some [path utilities](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_0/bpy.path.html) that you may want to use to easily get a path that is relative to the current blend file.

Answer (score 8):

You have following options. I use the file name *myfile.xxx* as placeholder for whatever file shall be opened.

#### Open within the folder where blender is installed:

```
    fout = open("myfile.xxx")
```

However you might run into permission issues when the installation folder is write protected.

#### Open in the user Application folder (Appdata)

```
    import bpy
    import os
    userdir = bpy.utils.resource_path('USER') # see note
    mypath  = os.path.join(userdir,"myfile.xxx")

    fout    = open(mypath)
```

**Note:** Please check also bpy.utils.user_resource(...)

#### Open in the same folder where the current blend file is located

```
    import bpy
    import os
    blenddir = py.path.abspath('//')
    mypath   = os.path.join(userdir, "myfile.xxx")

    fout     = open(mypath)
```

**Note:** If the current session has not yet been saved to a blend file, then blenddir is returned as empty string! You might need to test for this in your script.

#### Open in addon folder

```
    import bpy
    import os
    import myaddon
    myhome = os.path.dirname(myaddon.__file__)
    mypath = os.path.join(myhome, "myfile.xxx")

    fout     = open(mypath)
```

**Hint:** When you have installed the Addon by using the Addon Tab in User Preferences, then myhome points to Blender's *scripts/addons/myaddon* folder in the Appdata directory.

#### Open in Preset folder (where to store addon presets)

```
    import bpy
    import os
    import myaddon
    presets   = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', "presets")
    mypresets = os.path.join(presets, myaddon.__name__)
    if not os.path.exists(mypresets):
        os.makedirs(mypresets)    
    mypath = os.path.join(mypresets, "myfile.xxx")

    fout     = open(mypath)
```